# the meaning of chaining proportional statement?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm very new to physic. I do understand the basic concept of proportional.

it says if $$L \alpha S$$
then $$L= kS$$

I understand this part. but my professor says that

$$L \alpha S$$

and 
$$M \alpha S^3$$

then:

$$M \alpha S^3\alpha L^3$$

i really don't get the last line

I do understand that 
$$M= j(S^3)$$

but i don't understand the connection between the three. why this statement is valid?

$$M \alpha S^3\alpha L^3$$

Can someone show me the relationship between the three in basic elementary algebra?

Comment: Both answers below implicitly assume (in their first steps) that the variables $L$ and $M$ depend on each other. [If these two variables are independent of each other, then in fact $M$ is inversely proportional to $l^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4724632/21813), and your nonstandard notation $M \propto S^3\propto L^3$ is not read transitively.

Answer (score 1):

Formally, if you have $L \propto S$ then there is a non-zero factor $k$ such that $L = kS$. Take the cubic power of both sides: $L^3 = k^3S^3$ and now divide by $k^3$ (you can do it since $k$ is non-zero):
$$S^3 = \frac{1}{k^3}L^3.$$
This means $S^3 \propto L^3$. If further $M \propto S^3$ then you can write $M \propto S^3 \propto L^3$.

Comment: can you please also show $M \propto S^3 \propto L^3$ in the equality form?

Comment: There is no equality of the three terms, there are just two different equalities, i.e. $M = jS^3$ and $S^3 = \frac{1}{k^3}L^3$. This is equivalent to saying that $M \propto S^3 \propto L^3$.

Answer (score 1):

$L \propto S \implies L = k_1S$ for some $k_1 \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$
Cubing this equation we get,
$$L^3 = (k_1^3) S^3$$ 
Rearranging give us the following, $S^3 = \frac{L^3}{k_1^3}$.
$M \propto S^3 \implies M = k_2S^3$  for some $k_2 \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
Now substituting in the equality that we had earlier got $M = k_2\cdot\left(\frac{L^3}{k_1^3}\right) = \left( \frac{k_2}{k_1^3}\right)L^3$
$$\therefore M \propto L^3$$